# Python Lists append mutable variable

Tags: python, list, variables, append, mutable

Still new to programming/scripting, and this one's been bothering me. I have a function that searches through a list of names, comparing it to a template list of names, and when it finds a match, it places it in my final list in the correct order. For some later functions to work correctly, I need to be able to append some of these names as arrays/lists with. I'm running into the problem that every time I need to add a list to the final list, as soon as I change the variable, the final list updates with it. How do I fix this?

```
 light = ['template of names in here in correct order']
 listUser = ['names gathered from user input']

 for userChan in listUser: 
      for channelName in light:
         #check if channelName is a list or string

         if isinstance(channelName, basestring):
         #search for matches in userchan
             print channelName, 'is a string'
             if channelName in userChan.lower():
                 matchFound = True
                 listLight.append(userChan)
         else:
             print channelName, 'is a list'
             for piece in channelName:
                 print 'searching %s in %s' %(piece, userChan.lower())

                 if piece in userChan.lower():
                     print "found %s in %s" %(piece, userChan.lower())
                     lightMultList.append(piece)
                     matchFound = True
                     if len(lightMultList) == 2:
                        listLight.append(lightMultList)
                        del lightMultList[:]
```

So my problem is with the lightMultList. It's always going to be limited to 2 elements, but it changes. Hopefully this wasn't worded too horribly..

Comment: I can't quiet tell what your trying to do, but my guess is you where ever you append a list you'll want to make a copy of it instead of appending the actual list. So `listLight.append(lightMultList[:])`

Comment: Yup. That was it. Super simple. THANK YOU

Comment: @CG7Son: There's a better solution in this case. Just stop reusing `lightMultList` by clearing it out (`del lightMultList[:]`) and re-filling it.

Comment: I agree with @Hoopdady. `del lightMultList[:]` clears the list that you just appended to listLight - if you look at listLight[-1] right after the del, you'll see the problem. An alternate is to just create a new list `lightMultList = []` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're only ever creating one `lightMultList`. You repeatedly clear it out (with `del lightMultList[:]`) and re-fill it, and append the same thing over and over to `lightList`.

The simple fix is to just create a new `lightMultList` each time. Which you can do by changing this line:

```
del lightMultList[:]
```

… to:

```
lightMultList = []
```

This kind of problem is often a result of trying to directly porting C or C++ code, or just thinking in C++. If you were expecting `lightList.append(lightMultList)` to call a "copy constructor", that's the root problem: there is no such thing in Python. Assigning a value to a variable, appending it to a list, etc., doesn't copy anything; it just binds another reference to the same value.

Also, a C++ programmer might try to optimize performance by avoiding the wasteful creation of all those temporary objects by trying to reuse the same one, but in Python, the cost of creating a new list is about the same as the cost of iterating one step over `listUser` in the first place. If it's slow enough to worry about, you're going to have to reorganize your code or move the whole thing to C or Cython anyway; this isn't going to help. (That being said, it's rarely a useful optimization in C++ either; the right thing to do there, on the rare occasions where it matters, is to construct the new vector in-place within the containing vector…)